mariadb .my.cnf, Multiple host, user, pass, db entries support
Exactly same ask as here,
At the moment one can only put a single host, user, pass, db entry in .my.cnf file.
Has such limitation been  removed and now support multiple entries yet?
Note,

This is a feature request is for clients, not for servers.
The proposed [mysql1] ... [mysql2] ... sections is no good, as we need to use [client] instead of [mysql], so as to be able to work for both the mysql and mysqldump apps (and probably others too).

